# What means the description in "ENOLCK" error return?

Tags: nfs, man

I have a NFS server and a NFS client mounting the exported directories from the server. I created a small C++ program for getting more information why some operation on the client does not work withing mounted NFS directory. This small message returns, that I have an "ENOLCK" error. In the description (https://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf), there is written that

```
Too many segment locks open, lock table is full.
```

What does this description mean? Which table? Is there a way I can look at that table? Where is the size defined?

Comment: NFS in general does not support file locking.